# How to create executable script to run job after one another using bash scripting?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Good day! I am new in bash scripting and wanted to learn more.

I am currently executing hourly jobs for reprocessing and wanted to automate it by executing shell script to loop the next job after finishing the first one.

In command line we use executable script to run the hourly jobs;

```
./exec_oozie_jobs.sh FIX TOPUP DOMAIN_LENS HOURLY 2019100217,2019100218
```

This command will run the hourly job dated October 2 2019 17:00 and October 2 2019 18:00

What I want is to automatically run the next 2 hours job without executing the scripts again. Looping the job until I get the full 24 hrs.

```
./exec_oozie_jobs.sh FIX TOPUP DOMAIN_LENS HOURLY 2019100219,2019100220
```

This will reduce my monitoring.

Comment: I don't understand the question: You do have a command, which runs an hourly job twice (at 5 pm and at 6 pm). And now you want to run the same command DURING the following 2 hours, but not later than midnight????

Comment: Hi. This is for reprocessing. I just want to create the script which can run  second command after the first command ended successfully in oozie. Is it possible?

Comment: How do you define successfulness? If it is exit code 0, than `x && y` executes command y iff command x terminated with exit code 0.

Comment: why don't you use contab or a cronjob?